# how to use ffmpeg merge multi audio to multi video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am new to FFmpeg and I am trying to merge multi-audio with my multi-video. first, I try to remove all audio from the video and merge that video with my MP3.it's working for the first line but for the second line it's not working and i am not sure that it's correct or not Thank you for helping me

```
aa = for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -an "Videos\%%~na.mp4"


for %%b in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg -i aa -i "%%b" -c:v copy -c:a mp3 "Combine\%%~na.mp4"
```

Comment: I'm not skilled in Windows batch, but what does contain `aa` after the first command? Do you expect it contain filenames? I don't think so... But even if it does, you cannot enter multiple files after a single `-i`

Comment: it's already work with this command for remove audio

Comment: aa = for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -an "Videos\%%~na.mp4"

Comment: aa just a variable that i am declare

Comment: This does answer my question: what do you expect in `aa` after the first command, and what does it really contain? Since you are using it in the second command it is important to check its content. Moreover, when something "is not working", you have to copy/paste the error message.

Comment: What you are trying to do is actually unclear. You have a set of mp4 files and a set of mp3 files. Is there a one-to-one correspondances between the mp4 files and the mp3 files? i.e. name1.mp4 and name1.mp3, name2.mp4 and name2.mp3, etc... ? And you want for **each pair** to combine the video and the audio parts ?

Comment: Or do you want to merge everything into a single file at the end?

Comment: it's just a random file 1 audio to 1 video

Comment: It's not **a** random file, your question and the fact you have loops suggest that you have many files, not **a** file. But it's completely unclear how you want to combine them. PLease edit your question with an example of a list of files.